# Analytics SDK for Android that provide live statistics?

Tags: android, analytics, usage-statistics

Is there any Analytics SDK that provide users who are using the app right now live ? does flurry do this ?

Answer (score 1):

E.g. [TestFlight SDK](http://testflightapp.com/sdk) does it, as well as [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/). 
(But with TestFlight you get full SDK features for beta use only, i.e. if your app is signed with debug key.)

TestFlight shows you stuff like this (as detailed as you like, depending on checkpoints you've added in your code) almost instantly, within seconds:

[image]

Google Analytics reports include "Real-Time" section. (But in my experience, there can be a random delay before data reported from Android apps actually appears on Google Analytics website.)

[image]